# What does killing Roshan do?

Tags: dota-2

At the start of a game, I noticed that some of my team-mates were heading towards a spot on the map marked with a monster. I followed them to a monster which when I clicked was called "Roshan".

I thought that killing Roshan might do something special but we never ending up killing him.

**What do you get from killing Roshan?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Roshan](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Roshan) provides several bonuses to the team that kills him:

1. He provides 150-400 gold (depending on how strong he is) to the killer and an additional 200 gold to every member on the team that kills him.
2. He provides a good amount of experience, especially at lower levels.
3. He drops an item called [Aegis of the Immortal](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Roshan#Aegis_and_Cheese), which automatically resurrects the holder if they die with the aegis in their inventory but will disappear after 6 minutes if unused.
4. After killing him for the third time, he will start dropping cheese, which is an one time use instant 2500hp 1000mana restoration item.

Roshan spawns at the beginning of the game, and respawns 10 minutes after he was last killed.  And he also gets stronger as the game goes on, powering up every 5 minutes.

Comment: additional: He reclaims the Aegis of the Immortal after 6 min (it will disappear from your inventory)

Comment: You should really consider updating this, since the Roshan mechanics are not these anymore!

Comment: Agreed that this should be updated, Roshan now respawns at a random time between 8-11 minutes.